# How plot a function (using pgfplots) using a specific domain for one and specific coordinates for another?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot 2 curves (`x^5`), but one is using the domain `50-140` and the other one just in the specific points.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Gráfico (c)}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = Entrada(n),ylabel = Tempo(s), samples at={50,55,60,...,145,150}]

        \addplot[color=red,mark=x]coordinates {
            (50,        4.991e+000)
            (70,        2.704e+001)
            (100,       1.717e+002)
            (120,       4.696e+002)
            (140,       8.876e+002)
        };

        \addplot[blue,thick]{(x)^(5)};

        \legend{Estimado,Modelo}
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to plot the one with specific domain, using the coordinates for x^5

Comment: `\addplot[blue,thick,domain=50:140]{(x)^(5)};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for this case, you won't need `samples at={50,55,60,...,145,150}`. Once this is removed, you can use `domain` key to plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = Entrada(n),ylabel = Tempo(s), %samples at={50,55,60,...,145,150}
    ]

        \addplot[color=red,mark=x]coordinates {
            (50,        4.991e+000)
            (70,        2.704e+001)
            (100,       1.717e+002)
            (120,       4.696e+002)
            (140,       8.876e+002)
        };

        \addplot[blue,thick,domain=50:140]{(x)^(5)};

        %\legend{Estimado,Modelo}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed the legend just to show the end points of graphs.

---

The `y` values for the red line are too small compared to that of blue line. So the red line appears linear with that `y scale`. Here is how it happens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = Entrada(n),ylabel = Tempo(s), %samples at={50,55,60,...,145,150}
    ]

        \addplot[color=red,mark=x]coordinates {
            (50,        4.991e+000)
            (70,        2.704e+001)
            (100,       1.717e+002)
            (120,       4.696e+002)
            (140,       8.876e+002)
        };

        \addplot[blue,thick,restrict y to domain={0:1000}]{(x)^(5)};

        \legend{Estimado,Modelo}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also read page 337 of `pgfplots` manual for more on restricting the domains.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I want the red line to be plotted like the blue one.        It should be a curve, and not a line segment. What is going wrong  with the points plot?

Comment: It is because the `y` vakues for the red plot are too small. So the line appears linear. I will do some edits.